# Meteor, Form validation and Bootstrap accordion

Tags: meteor

I have a form in a Meteor application that contains a list of radio buttons that is made accessible by a Bootstrap accordion. I have implemented a validation routing in meteor that inserts classes into the input elements to mark them as valid/invalid.

Problem is: Everytime a validation state of one input element changes, the template is redrawn and the currently open accordion closes.

I solved this by doing this clumsy approach:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    // track collapse state of accordion....
$('.collapse').on('shown', function() {
    Session.set(addBookingCollapse, $(this).attr('id'));
});
});

Template.addrecord.helpers({
    openAccordion: function(accordion) {
        if (Session.get(addBookingCollapse) == accordion) {
            return 'in'
        };
    }
});

<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body 
collapse {{openAccordion 'collapseOne'}}">
```

...and so on for the other four collapsible elements

But for whoever's sake, there must be a more elegant solution? I do not want to waste a session variable for this....

Answer (score 1):

It may help to put the input elements in `{{#isolate}}{{\isolate}}` blocks to avoid re-rendering the entire template. See: [Meteor Isolates](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate)

Comment: Yes, did not help. Well, I got rid of the accordion in the end.

Comment: I ran into this redraw issue a lot, with other jQuery plugins etc.  I finally resorted to using session variables like you to track whether the element was redrawn, and only let the component redraw the first time it hit the Template.mytemplate.render = function(){} section. Using IronRouter, I unset the variable on route change. The new Shark branch of Meteor should work very well in these cases, and will be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really looked super close at your code/problem, but why do you use id's to target each of them on their own? Why not use a class for all of them like this:

```
$('.a-class-that-you-name').on('shown', function() {
    var thisSpecificId = $(this).attr('id');
    Session.set('addBookingCollapse', thisSpecificId);
});
```

Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, that would get rid of some of the uglyness. But I am against the whole tracking opening state in a session variable. Isn't there a way to circumvent this with .preserve or constant regions? I tried, but I have not found a way.

Comment: Updated the question to match this suggestion.